# BeBuilder Post title issues

Tags: wordpress

I work on a site using Be Builder theme. recently I noticed that the  tag has a statement that is the same on all posts, regardless of the title I have set for every single post.
any idea why this happened?

I checked all the titles again and even the main description for the website. I searched over the web and didn't find the answer.